# Почему команды,набранные в консоли от руки срабатывают, а в makefile - нет?

Tags: makefile

Я хочу создать makefile для статической компиляции библиотеки freetype в `ubuntu`. Из её инструкции по установке было выяснено, что

```
The following  should work  on all Unix  systems where  the `make'
    command invokes GNU Make:

      ./configure [options]
      make
      make install           (as root)

    The default installation path  is `/usr/local'.  It can be changed
    with the `--prefix=<path>' option.  Example:

      ./configure --prefix=/usr
```

Только к этому сделано небольшое дополнение: мне нужны только статические и не нужны динамические библиотеки. В силу этого команды,которые я набираю руками в консоль выглядят следующим образом:

```
elvin@ubuntu:~/lab1/freetype$ ./configure --prefix=/home/elvin/lab1/freetype --enable-freetype-config --enable-static --disable-shared
```

Сработало без ошибок и запустилось без sudo. 
Затем(по документации) выполняем команду `make`:

```
elvin@ubuntu:~/lab1/freetype$ make
```

Небольшой кусок её output'a:

```
./builds/unix/libtool --mode=compile gcc -pedantic -ansi -I/home/elvin/.local/share/Trash/files/freetype.16/objs -I./builds/unix -I/home/elvin/.local/share/Trash/files/freetype.16/include  -c -Wall -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/include -DFT_CONFIG_CONFIG_H="<ftconfig.h>" -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DFT_CONFIG_MODULES_H="<ftmodule.h>" -DFT_CONFIG_OPTIONS_H="<ftoption.h>" -o /home/elvin/.local/share/Trash/files/freetype.16/objs/ftsystem.lo builds/unix/ftsystem.c
```

И финальный(должен быть sudo):

```
elvin@ubuntu:~/lab1/freetype$ sudo make install
```

Всё собралось без проблем и статическая библиотека появилась.

Теперь проворачиваю то же , но с помощью makefile:

```
PathFreetype:=freetype

#to know the folder
mkfile_path2 := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
mkfile_dir2 := $(dir $(mkfile_path2))
#makefile узнает,где он
LIB:=lib
empty:=
space:= $(empty) $(empty)

mkfile_dir2:=$(subst $(space),$(empty),$(mkfile_dir2))
mkfile_dir2:=$(mkfile_dir2)$(PathFreetype)
#удаляю пробел в конце пути к папке и дописываю freetype
# we need this to make static compile of libpng as it requiers the full absolute path to create a static lib ./configure [--prefix=/path] <---— path!
static:
echo "$(mkfile_dir2)" #проверяю,что имя папки уже с freetype
cd $(mkfile_dir2) && sudo ./configure —prefix=$(mkfile_dir2) --enable-freetype-config --enable-static --disable-shared ; make ; sudo $(MAKE) install

Запускаю: elvin@ubuntu:~/lab1$ make static
```

Но make не срабатывает и выдаётся такая ошибка:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/elvin/lab1/freetype'
./builds/unix/libtool --mode=compile gcc -pedantic -ansi -I/home/elvin/lab1/freetype/objs -I./builds/unix -I/home/elvin/lab1/freetype/include  -c -Wall -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/include -DFT_CONFIG_CONFIG_H="<ftconfig.h>" -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DFT_CONFIG_MODULES_H="<ftmodule.h>" -DFT_CONFIG_OPTIONS_H="<ftoption.h>" -o /home/elvin/lab1/freetype/objs/ftsystem.lo builds/unix/ftsystem.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -pedantic -ansi -I/home/elvin/lab1/freetype/objs -I./builds/unix -I/home/elvin/lab1/freetype/include -c -Wall -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/include "-DFT_CONFIG_CONFIG_H=<ftconfig.h>" -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY "-DFT_CONFIG_MODULES_H=<ftmodule.h>" "-DFT_CONFIG_OPTIONS_H=<ftoption.h>" builds/unix/ftsystem.c -o /home/elvin/lab1/freetype/objs/ftsystem.o
builds/unix/ftsystem.c:19:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ft2build.h>
```

Как видите , почему-то make(ручной) и makefilовский заходят в разные директории почему-то
Почему происходит такая ошибка и как её исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. строки, начинающиеся с `cd` и `echo` — это у вас явно рецепт. тогда в начале этих двух строк нужен символ табуляции.
2. и `sudo` перед `./configure` не нужно.
3. и опечатка: `—prefix` вместо `--prefix`
4. и `prefix` уж точно не должен совпадать с каталогом, где находятся исходники.
5. и зачем все эти сложные манипуляции с именами и каталогами? ведь можно гораздо проще (запускать лучше в пустом каталоге):

```
f = freetype-2.10.1
a = $(f).tar.gz

static: $(f)
    cd $< && ./configure --prefix=$(PWD)/$@ --enable-freetype-config --enable-static --disable-shared
    $(MAKE) -C $<
    $(MAKE) -C $< install

$(f): $(a)
    tar -xf $<

$(a):
    wget https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/$@

clean:
    -rm -rf $(f)

distclean: clean
    -rm -rf static $(a)
```